# Get data from table with id from another table

Tags: mysql

i have two Tables `users_data` and `users_statistics`

users_data:

```
id    money     position   uid
1     1000      20921      3
2     3000      8742       0
3     2000      23214      3
```

users_statistics:

```
id    lastname   lastlogin
1     Hans       13.05.2200
2     Uwe        10.03.1900
3     Herbert    13.42.2421
```

Now, i want to SELECT all `lastname` WHERE `uid` = 3

My try was

```
 SELECT `lastname` FROM users_statistics
 JOIN users_data USING (id)
 WHERE `uid` = 3
```

With this Query he returns me all 3 Rows, but why?

In the second row the uid is 0...

I hop someone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: [It looks good to me.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fffb/1) Perhaps you have an extra record or something you aren't sharing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds weird but now it works...

I only changed the `uid` to `users_data.uid`

```
SELECT `lastname` FROM users_statistics
JOIN users_data USING (id)
WHERE users_data.uid = 3
```

Now he only gives me the two rows with `uid` = 3

When someone can explain this, let me know it :D

Answer (score -1):

your query works for me:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5025/1

Also tested under local MySQL 5.5.38

Comment: This is not an answer. You might want to go with comment next time.

Comment: i know, i tried to comment but i must have 50 reputation, so what can i do?